# hibernate column type problem (MySql)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, types, mapping

I am getting this exeption:
`Can not set int field com.affiliates.hibernate.Employee.employeeId to java.lang.Integer`
while tring to fetch results from creteria:

```
Transaction t = getSession().beginTransaction();

DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Affiliate.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("employee", 1));
List l = c.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).list();
t.commit();
```

running the query in the database returning results fine.

These are my Affiliate and Employee beans:

```
@Entity(name="AFFILIATE")
public class Affiliate extends HibernateBean{ 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="AFFILIATE_ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Employee employee;
        //other memebers + get and set
}

@Entity(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends HibernateBean implements ILoginAble{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int employeeId;
        //other memebers + get and set
}
```

these are the tables:

```
Create Table
CREATE TABLE `AFFILIATE` (
  `AFFILIATE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EMPLOYEE_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AFFILIATE_ID`),

  KEY `fk_AFFILIATE_EMPLOYEE1` (`EMPLOYEE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AFFILIATE_AFFILIATE1` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_ID`) REFERENCES `AFFILIATE` (`AFFILIATE_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AFFILIATE_EMPLOYEE1` FOREIGN KEY (`EMPLOYEE_ID`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`EMPLOYEE_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `EMPLOYEE` (
  `EMPLOYEE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EMPLOYEE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

This is the full exeption:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: select this_.AFFILIATE_ID as AFFILIATE1_8_2_, this_.EMAIL as EMAIL8_2_, this_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE6_8_2_, this_.name as name8_2_, this_.PARENT_ID as PARENT7_8_2_, this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD8_2_, this_.USER_NAME as USER5_8_2_, employee2_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE1_2_0_, employee2_.EMAIL as EMAIL2_0_, employee2_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST3_2_0_, employee2_.IS_ACTIVE as IS4_2_0_, employee2_.LAST_NAME as LAST5_2_0_, employee2_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD2_0_, employee2_.REG_DATE as REG7_2_0_, employee2_.USER_NAME as USER8_2_0_, affiliate3_.AFFILIATE_ID as AFFILIATE1_8_1_, affiliate3_.EMAIL as EMAIL8_1_, affiliate3_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE6_8_1_, affiliate3_.name as name8_1_, affiliate3_.PARENT_ID as PARENT7_8_1_, affiliate3_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD8_1_, affiliate3_.USER_NAME as USER5_8_1_ from AFFILIATE this_ left outer join EMPLOYEE employee2_ on this_.EMPLOYEE_ID=employee2_.EMPLOYEE_ID left outer join AFFILIATE affiliate3_ on this_.PARENT_ID=affiliate3_.AFFILIATE_ID where this_.EMPLOYEE_ID=?
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.affiliates.hibernate.Employee.employeeId
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3619)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1728)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1699)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:342)
    at $Proxy14.list(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at com.affiliates.dao.BaseApplicationDao.getAll(BaseApplicationDao.java:43)
    at com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesApi.getAll(AffiliatesApi.java:39)
    at com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesAPITest.getAll(AffiliatesAPITest.java:22)
    at com.affiliates.api.AffiliatesAPITest.main(AffiliatesAPITest.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.affiliates.hibernate.Employee.employeeId to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:55)

... 28 more
```

Comment: There's also: "could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.affiliates.hibernate.Employee.employeeId", could you confirm that your getters and setters are according to the javabean naming conventions. Though this can also be caused by incorrect hibernate mappings.

Comment: @Hypnos - yes, the convesion (as you can see it) is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably with this restriction :

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("employee", 1));
```

This means : "make sure the employee field of the Affiliate instance is equal to 1".

But the employee field of the Affiliate class is not an int nor an Integer. It's an Employee.

Change your restriction to

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("employee.employeeId", 1));
```

I'm also surprised by the cascade type on the relationship between employee and affiliate. An employee has many affiliate, but when you delete one of the affiliate,you want the employee to be deleted. I doubt this works (you'll have constraints violations).

Answer (score 0):

Change all your fields of primitive types to Object Types. In your case `int` has to be `Integer`.

Like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Integer employeeId;

// don't forget to change the corresponding getters and setters.
```

Have a nice day
Thomas

Comment: Hi, Not working, already tried that. getting: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.affiliates.hibernate.Employee.employeeId to java.lang.Integer`. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Glad that JB Nizet had the right answer for you.